# expression of type 'string' can't be used to index type 'Object'. No index signature with a parameter of type 'string' was found on type 'Object'

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

html code:

```
<tr *ngFor = "let row of food;">
        <td *ngFor ="let col of headers;">
            {{row[col]}}
        </td>
    </tr>
```

angular component code:

```
export class FirstComponent implements OnInit {
    public header;
    food=[{Project_title: 'Avocado',
        Benefit: true,
        Completion_date:'01/10/2022',
        Project_description:160,
        Project_cost:'some long text some long text some long text',
        Accomplishments:'something',
        help_needed:'Yes',
        Project_leader:'XYZ',
        Project_Manager:'ABC',
        Savings:'Some very long text Some very long text Some very long text Some very long 
                     text Some very long text Some very long text',
        complete_status:'Completed'
        }]
    constructor() { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.headers=Object.keys(this.food[0]); \\this is used to assign all the keys in an array
    });
  }

}
```

I'm trying to extract each object from the array from food and print the values of array based on their corresponding key value.

Comment: Typo error. `public headers` but **not** `public header`.

Answer (score 0):

Change your code to this:

in **first.component.html**

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <th *ngFor="let column of headers">
      {{ column }}
    </th>
  </tr>
  <tr *ngFor="let row of rows">
    <td *ngFor="let column of headers">
      {{ row[column] }}
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

in **first.component.ts**

```
export class FirstComponent implements OnInit {
  headers = [];

  rows = [
    {
      Project_title: 'Avocado',
      Benefit: true,
      Completion_date: '01/10/2022',
      Project_description: 160,
      Project_cost: 'some long text some long text some long text',
      Accomplishments: 'something',
      Help_needed: 'Yes',
      Project_leader: 'XYZ',
      Project_Manager: 'ABC',
      Savings:
        'Some very long text Some very long text Some very long text Some very long text Some very long text Some very long text',
      complete_status: 'Completed',
    },
  ];

  constructor() {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.headers = Object.keys(this.rows[0]);
  }
```

Here is a working example: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-zmucpt?file=src/app/first.component.ts